# Azure Web App - Restrict access to API Management

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-api-management

I'm trying to setup a very simple Azure deployment that consists of a few Web Apps and an API Management Gateway through which all traffic is directed. The problem I currently have is that I am unsure as to the best way of blocking traffic from going direct to the Web Apps and bypassing the gateway. Is there a 'best practice' mechanism for ensuring only traffic from the Gateway is allowed through?

I've seen suggestions for IP range blocking and 'secret key' implementations, however I wonder whether there is a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Better from what perspective.  Are there specific problems with the solutions you have found so far?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I should I would add my own answer as I found that the new portal now has an 'API App' which allows access to API though internal only, e.g. through the gateway.

This seems to meet what I was trying to do exactly!

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-api-apps-why-best-platform/

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, just a link to the general overview of the Azure App Service

Comment: ALso Miao Jiangs answer is better because, that is actually how to do it. API App is also deprecated. Miaos answer is also how to do it if you are using Cloudflare as a reversed proxy, if you go with the mutual certificate solution.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options:
1. IP whitelisting
2. Secret key 
3. Basic auth
4. Mutual cert auth

IMO #4 is the best way. You can find out more information on how to enable the feature in API Management and Web Apps here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enabling-client-certificate-authentication-for-an-azure-web-app/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates/